# Writing complicated row level trigger In Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have to create a row level trigger on a table called Movies that will compute the five greatest movie ratings from this Movies table and insert a new table called TopMovies with these movies. Each time I put a new rating in the Movies table this trigger fires. I am really struggling to understand how to go about this.

The Movies table has the following attributes (Movie, Director, Rating)
The Top Movies table will have (Rating)

So far I have just the following code. I really am lost as to how to make it so that once I have inserted at least 5 ratings into the movies table, the TopMovies table will delete the lowest rated movie and re-populate it with a new movie. I am not asking for the answer but any help to go in the right direction

```
Create of replace Trigger top_trigger
After insert or update on Movies
For each row

Begin
   insert into TopMovies values (:new.rating),
End
```

Comment: What is the goal here with the table TopMovies ? Do you want to see top 5 movies of every day or store top five moveis of every moment ?

Comment: I am going to execute a series of insert statements into Movies. The TopMovies will have just the titles of the movies with the five greatest ratings. So top five of every moment.

Comment: So in the table TopMovies you will have 5 new records for every insert into Movies table. For example if you insert 2 new rows i Movies you will have 5 records in TopMovies ?

Comment: So both tables are started off with no values. For the Movies table when I insert one movie with all its values TopMovies will get one movie. When I insert a second row in Movies TopMovies will get a second movie. When I have inserted six movies in the Movies table then in TopMovies it will look to see if that movie is greater than the lowest rated movie in TopMovies and will remove and replace this with the new movie if it greater.

Comment: So why not creating a view ?

Comment: @VBoka - I suggest it's because this is a schoolwork assignment. Yet another example of how teachers struggle to come up with realistic use cases for triggers.

Comment: @APC exactly that.

Comment: My take is that this is a very, very poor use of a trigger.  All that calculation and update of TopMovies should be done directly by the application that is inserting into Movies.  Plus, you seem to indicate that TopMovies will only have the single row 'ratings'.  But then later you say "TopMovies will have _just the titles_ of the movies with the five greatest ratings".  I agree with @VBoka, that the whole thing (ranking of ratings) could be done with a view on Movies.  Unless as APC suggested, this is a poorly constructed homework assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `triggers`. But be aware that concurrent requests may change the expected behavior when you use the triggers.

**Trigger solution:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOP_TRIGGER AFTER
    INSERT OR UPDATE ON MOVIES
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    LV_CNT      NUMBER := 0;
    LV_RATING   TOPMOVIES.RATING%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1), MIN(RATING)
      INTO LV_CNT, LV_RATING
      FROM TOPMOVIES;

    IF LV_CNT >= 5 AND :NEW.RATING > LV_RATING THEN
        DELETE FROM TOPMOVIES WHERE RATING = LV_RATING;
    END IF;

    IF LV_CNT < 5 OR ( LV_CNT >= 5 AND :NEW.RATING > LV_RATING ) THEN
        INSERT INTO TOPMOVIES VALUES ( :NEW.RATING );
    END IF;

END;
/
```

The better solution is to use the view.

**VIEW solution:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TOPMOVIES_VW AS
    SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT T.*,
                   DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY RATING DESC) AS RANK#
              FROM MOVIES T
        )
    WHERE RANK# <= 5;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply and attempt at solving the problem. However I need the movie titles in the TopMovies and that is where I am having major trouble. Instead of LV_RATING TOPMOVIE.RATING%TYPE should I have something like LV_RATING TOPMOVIE.TILE%TYPE? Then would there be a way in the if statements I can somehow check the movie title from the Movies table to see if its rating is greater than any of the ratings in my TopMovies table?

Comment: @NoobCoder : You don't need to check the MOVIE_TITLE in TOPMOVIE to establish whether there's a spare slot in the table. If the new movie has a better rating than a movie in TOPMOVIE who cares what the dud one is called? Oh, and your question doesn't show you populating that column in the trigger, but I'm sure you can figure out how to change this code to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try below code -

```
Create of replace Trigger top_trigger
After insert or update on Movies
Declare
    v_movie_count  number:= 0;
Begin
    select count(*)
    into v_movie_count
    from Movies;

    if v_movie_count >= 5 then

       delete from TopMovies;

       INSERT INTO TopMovies
       SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT Rating, ROWNUM RN
             FROM Movies
             ORDER BY Rating)
       WHERE RN <= 5;
       /* You can use below statement if you are using 12C or higher*/
       /*INSERT INTO TopMovies
         SELECT Rating, ROWNUM RN
         FROM Movies
         ORDER BY Rating DESC
         FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;*/
    end if;
End
```

Comment: The Seeker says *"I have to create a row level trigger"*. So your statement level trigger won't get them a passing grade on the assignment.